# How to initialize MainMenuModel and SubMenuModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this menu model:

```
          public MainMenuModel(string transKey, string stateName, string displayUrl, string numberOfMenu, bool hasSubMenu, List<SubMenuModel> subMenu)
                {
                    TransKey = transKey;
                    StateName = stateName;
                    DisplayUrl = displayUrl;
                    NumberOfMenu = numberOfMenu;
                    HasSubMenu = hasSubMenu;
                    SubMenu = subMenu;
                }
                public string TransKey { get; set; }
                public string StateName { get; set; }
                public string DisplayUrl { get; set; }

                public string NumberOfMenu { get; set; }
                public bool HasSubMenu { get; set; }

                public List<SubMenuModel> SubMenu { get; 

    set; 
}
```

and i have submemnu model:

```
    public SubMenuModel(string transKey, string stateName, string displayUrl, string numberOfMenu)
    {
        TransKey = transKey;
        StateName = stateName;
        DisplayUrl = displayUrl;
        NumberOfMenu = numberOfMenu;

    }
    public string TransKey { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayUrl { get; set; }
    public string NumberOfMenu { get; set; }

}
```

My question is how to initialize menu and submenu? I tried this:

```
MainMenu.Add(new MainMenuModel("Promotions","default","default","6",true,new SubMenuModel("Promotions","default","default","3"));
```

But this is not working. Can someone please tell me how can i initialize this model if i have this structure of models or to modified somehow to be easier??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass SubMenuModel instead of List so you can try to do the following thing:

```
MainMenu.Add(new MainMenuModel("Promotions","default","default","6",true,
new List<SubMenuModel>(){
    new SubMenuModel("Promotions","default","default","3")
});
```

Comment: what if i want to made this submenumodel optional? how can i do that?

Comment: Beacuse it's reference type instead of passing new List object you can pass null or you can make optional parameter in constructor: public MainMenuModel(string transKey, string stateName, string displayUrl, string numberOfMenu, bool hasSubMenu, List<SubMenuModel> subMenu = null)

Answer (score 1):

Your MainMenuModel has a List so you must initialize a list there.

```
var subMenuList = new List<SubMenuModel>()
    {
        new SubMenuModel("Promotions","default","default","3")
    }; 

var mainMenuModel = new MainMenuModel("Promotions","default","default","6",true,subMenuList);

MainMenu.Add(mainMenuModel);
```